# How to remove test orders in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I need to remove the test orders from the magento backend, and from the user panels. I found one useful idea but its does not working for some reason. Can you advice to solve this issues?

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);                                                                                                                 
//replace your own orders numbers here:
$test_order_ids=array(
  '200000091',
  '200000090',
  '200000089',
  '200000088',
  '200000087',
  '200000086'
);

foreach($test_order_ids as $id){
    try{
        Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id)->delete();
        echo "order #".$id." is removed".PHP_EOL;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "order #".$id." could not be remvoved: ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo "complete.";
?>

<?php
$today = getdate();
print_r($today);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html), (it's free :-) ). You never know when you'll gonna need to delete other orders.

Comment: I use an extension to accomplish this same thing. Works great for me.